# Unable to get element by ID with selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

This is my page:

```
<table class="formarea" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="form_label_40">
            <script>prints(ot_login_username);</script>Username&nbsp;:</td>
        <!--<td></td>-->
        <td>
            <input type="text" maxlength="16" size="12" id="login_name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="form_label_40">
                <b>
                    <script>prints(ot_login_password);</script>Password&nbsp;:</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" maxlength="16" size="12" id="login_pass">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <!--<script>prints("<input type='button' value='"+ot_login_login+"' onclick='checkForm();'>");</script>-->

                </td>
            </tr>
```

I'm trying to get the elements `login_name` and `login_pass` using selenium:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_name"))
driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass_name"))
```

But I'm getting the error `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element'`
Why?

Comment: try using some waits  implicit wait or ExplicitWait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the `HTML` you have shared you have tried to locate the elements **login_name** and **login_pass** through `id` which is  not identifying the elements uniquely. To identify the uniquely you have to adopt a `Locator Strategy` as follows :

```
//login_name field
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='formarea']//input[@id='login_name']"))
//login_pass field
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='formarea']//input[@id='login_pass']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies with the following code in selenium: 
`driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass_name"))`, but in the html the id your looking for is: `<input type="password" maxlength="16" size="12" id="login_pass">` i.e, login_pass.

Correct me if I'm wrong...

BTW, if i understand correctly, X-Path is susceptible to changes in the code :/